# Extracting as much information from a browser request as possible?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web, fraud-prevention

I am currently working on project that involves identifying spammers which are creating fake accounts on my site. I am interested to know what type of information I would be able to extract.

First of all, there is browser fingerprinting. According to the library https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2, there is about 25 features that I can use.

Then there is platform detection, available at https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/. This library seems to be able to extract some information about the uesrs' platforms.

And then I could also extract information from my http server by inspecting the environment.

Are there any other techniques I could use to extract information from my requests?

Comment: Why not just use a captcha?

Comment: Has to happen at routing request level